# innerHTML alternative or replace onchange event with a div

Tags: javascript, dom-events, onchange, innerhtml

I am stuck with a problem and I need you people to help me out.

I have a html form. It sends country, state, city and pin code(to be entered manually) to a php file to process with help of ajax. Once submitted it returns with the pin code value in the text box.

What I want is, whenever a user changes the value of pin code for the second time the form needs to be reset.

What I have done is, I used innerHTML like this:

```
<form id="someid" method="post">
<input type="text" value="'.$_POST['pin-code'].'" onChange="resetpin();" />
```

The reset form is like this:

```
function resetpin() {
document.getElementById('someid').innerHTML = Full HTML CODE FROM ABOVE FORM GOES HERE
```

This code becomes ugly as the .innerHTML contains all the code for selecting country, city, state which gets repeated two time in the same page.

So what I thought was, can I be able to do something like this?

When user changes pin for the second time the form need to get reset like.

```
onchange=showdiv("ID of the form and contents to be displayed")
```

Can I be able to do this so that I do not need to use innerHTML...

Please help me out.

Comment: Why not use `form.reset()`? As in `document.getElementById('someid').reset()`. Or even `onchange="this.form.reset()"` might work.

Answer (score 0):

Your `resetpin` function needs to loop through the input elements of the form resetting their values (excepting for the pin presumably).